# .Net code execution just stops, no exception thrown

Tags: .net, dll, exception

I have a VB.Net class that I am calling via a manual thread from an asp.net page. When code execution tries to call a particular an external DLL execution just stops. No exception is thrown. I write to a log right before the call and right after as well as in the error handler. Only the log entry right before the call is recorded.

This is working fine on my dev machine, but it failing on the deployment server. I was using a demo version earlier today that was working.

I had a similar thing happen with a different third party dll earlier this week. Turned out I had a different build of the component installed on the server. I looked for that in this case, but I have the same version in both my bin folder and the dll's install folder anmd on my dev machine.

Any idea how I go about figuring out what is going on here?

Comment: After about 7 minutes an exception is finally thrown: "Thread was being aborted". Does this mean the DLL is blocking/locking/looping or some other such thing? Is this exception coming from the dll or from the CLR?

Comment: Ok, found the problem. It looks like this is very specific to the DLL and my situation. The DLL, websitesscreenshot.dll does screencaps of other web sites. It uses IE in background to cap the page to an image. The page I was capturing on my server had mixed ssl/non ssl (secure/nonsecure) content and IE was popping up an invisible dialog to that effect. This was hanging the DLL until the thread died. I was not missing any exceptions because the dll was hung and not sending one. Changing IE security settings to allow mixed content did not solve the problem. Changing all of my http to https did.

Answer (score 0):

You don't offer any details about the external DLL, although you mention "demo version". This is just guessing: Could there be some licensing issues? The DLL checks whether you're running on development server and works fine there but on production server (IIS I assume) it doesn't. The delay could be related to the DLL trying to contact a licencing server.

Actually there could be another reason: you have a valid license but the deployment server cannot contact the Internet.

Also, check that your deployment server can access crl.microsoft.com. Some addins try to access that to revocate some certificates. More information about that:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Windows-MSI/29381925/code-signing-performance-problems-with-certificate-revocation-chec.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some logging information in the dll that you are calling. Frameworks like log4net can be useful for this, then find out how far the code gets in the dll.

Answer (score 0):

One method I have used before is to log any assembly bindings using the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

After you have run the application, you can check the logs to find what has errored/failed.

Comment: That looks like a good tool, I will have to add it to my chest.

Comment: it's very handy...if you have an issue with an assembly you will see where and how .NET is searching for it.